# How to find the latest record of each group partition by column name in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to get top 1 record ordered by devicetimestamp grouped by deviceimei. I want to count how many records there area which have VL1 < 350 of latest record according to timestamp desc.

Query

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
         *, 
         rank() over (partition by deviceimei order by devicetimestamp desc) as data_rank 
     from 
         [TransTrak_V_1.0].[dbo].[Current_Voltage])
where 
    datarank = 1
```

Sample dataset

```
A_id    DeviceImei  DeviceTimeStamp VL1 VL2 VL3 IL1 IL2 IL3 VL12    VL23    VL31    AVL INUT    data_rank
999165  8628180465463   2020-10-05 11:45:05.000 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
999163  8628180465463   2020-10-05 11:41:32.000 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
999161  8628180465463   2020-10-05 11:38:23.000 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ROW_NUMBER` inside a CTE could work.

Essentially what we are doing is creating a sequential row count based on your deviceimei ordered by the datetime field.

```
;WITH top_n AS (

    SELECT v.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY v.DeviceImei ORDER BY v.DeviceTimeStamp DESC) as Seq 
    FROM #Voltage v
)

SELECT   COUNT(DeviceImei) AS [RowCount]
FROM     top_n
WHERE    VL1 < 350
AND      Seq = 1
GROUP BY DeviceImei
```

---

```
RowCount
1
```

### Setup

```
-- Drop a temporary table called '#Voltage'
-- Drop the table if it already exists
IF OBJECT_ID('tempDB..#Voltage', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Voltage
GO
-- Create the temporary table from a physical table called 'TableName' in schema 'dbo' in database 'DatabaseName'
CREATE TABLE #Voltage 
(
     A_id              BIGINT 
   , DeviceImei        BIGINT                        
   , DeviceTimeStamp   DATETIME2(2)                         
   , VL1               INT             
   , VL2               INT             
   , VL3               INT             
   , IL1               INT             
   , IL2               INT             
   , IL3               INT             
   , VL12              INT             
   , VL23              INT             
   , VL31              INT             
   , AVL               INT             
   , INUT              INT             
   , data_rank         INT                 
)

INSERT INTO #Voltage 
VALUES 
(999165,8628180465463, '20201005 11:45:05.000', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
(999163,8628180465463, '20201005 11:41:32.000', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2),
(999161,8628180465463, '20201005 11:38:23.000', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3)
```